# Who takes care of freeing MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID structure when calling GetExtendedTcpTable via ctypes in Python?

Tags: python, memory, ctypes

I'm calling [GetExtendedTcpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) via ctypes in Python.

For this I'm declaring the following structures:

```
    class MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('dwState', DWORD),
                ('dwLocalAddr', DWORD),
                ('dwLocalPort', DWORD),
                ('dwRemoteAddr', DWORD),
                ('dwRemotePort', DWORD),
                ('dwOwningPid', DWORD)]
```

And:

```
    class MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('dwNumEntries', DWORD),
                ('table', MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID * ANY_SIZE)]
```

Where ANY_SIZE is initialized via a first call to GetExtendedTcpTable.

My question is who takes care of deallocating the memory taken by the 'table' field above? Which is an Array of MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID structures.

Or maybe my question should be: who allocates the MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID structures in the array? GetExtendedTcpTable or Python?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have to allocate sufficient space in `table` before calling `GetExtendedTcpTable`. And then when that call returns you need to deallocate it, although `ctypes` will do that for you.

If you have obtained `ANY_SIZE` by calling `GetExtendedTcpTable` with `pTcpTable` as `NULL` then you have nothing special to do.  You create an instance of `MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID` and sufficient buffer is created for you.

Comment: So do I need to allocate the space or ctypes takes care of it?

Comment: `MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID * ANY_SIZE` takes care of it, so long as `MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID` is defined after `ANY_SIZE` has been set.